# VSCode/NodeJS live-server execution issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, liveserver, npm-live-server

**Getting an error while running live-server command on VSCode and as well as on Command Prompt.**

File cannot be loaded. The file is not digitally
signed. You cannot run this script on the current system. For more information about running scripts and setting execution policy, see about_Execution_Policies at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

- live-server --version
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
  ```

Installed NodeJS and changed my Env variables to npm.

Comment: You should probably change the execution policy to allow unsigned scripts to run e.g. `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser` as it says in the linked Microsoft documentation.

Comment: Open powershell as administrator and run the command.